# Chrome Website Test?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've just about finished a website, but the only problem is when I test it in Chrome (I've tested the other browsers and this issue doesnt occur), and the only thing that loads is the navigation bar. When i click 'home' on the navigation bar, the entire thing loads up but it doesn't when you type in the initial [www.peach-designs.com](http://www.peach-designs.com)

So I'm not sure how to get around this problem - www.peach-designs.com/index.php is working, but not www.peach-designs.com.

Hope somebody can help with this, as this is the final few hurdles to get over before its finished.

Kind Regards,

Snakespan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is an issue with jCarousel in Google Chrome, others have reported the same problem: http://google.com/search?q=jCarousel+Chrome